# c++ prototyping classes, structs, and functions

Tags: c++, prototype

I'm attempting to use a class inside a struct, which seems to be no problem if I declare the class first:

```
class Foo {
}
stuct Bar {
    Foo example[5];    // array of Foos
}
```

This seems fragile. It should work in whatever order like functions use prototypes for. I tried prototyping them, but this doesn't work.

```
class Foo;
struct Bar;

stuct Bar {
    Foo example[5];
}
class Foo {
}
```

Why doesn't this work? 
Error code C2079 (on visual studio): 'Bar::Foo' uses undefined class 'Foo'.
Error code C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes.
Both on the errors occur on Foo example[5];

Also, would it be appropriate to keep my function prototypes above the ADTs (abstract data types) so I can use the functions inside them, or should I write the function inside the ADT?

Comment: You need a [mcve]. You have countless syntax errors and typos, making it difficult to understand. Also, the error message would be helpful

Comment: You need the complete definition of a class or struct before you use it in a way that requires the size to be known, such as making an array of them.

Comment: @Retired Ninja That's helpful, I didn't realize this was called forward declaration so I didn't find it in my search.

Comment: Knowing the name of what you're looking for is often the hardest part. :)